# document.write is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make it "document.write" but it doesn't come up. I'm using Dreamweaver.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Untitled Document</title> 
<script> 
  x=0;
  function newPerson(){
    x++;
    document.write(x);
    var pname = "p" + x;
    var jj =document.forms["frm1"]["fname"].value;
    var gg =document.forms["frm1"]["lname"].value;
    document.write(pname + jj + gg);
  }

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <form name="frm1" onSubmit="newPerson()">

  First Name: <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"/> <br/>
  Last Name: <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"/><br/>
  <input type="submit" value="update"/>  </form>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: I think your page could be getting redirected due to default form submit.

Comment: **-1 for the title**: _"Can someone please tell me whats wrong with this simple html/javascript code"_

Comment: Do your best never to use `document.write()`.

Comment: mention type attribute in script tag as "text/javascript" and  i am not getting why you have declare x outside the function.

Comment: @SatyamKoyani Thats not compulsary to provide type for the script. And  x has a global scope maybe thats why he declared that way.

Comment: How can I bypass using document.write?

Comment: In addition to the point I mentioned earlier, the `document.write(x)` line is clearing away your page and hence the `fname` and `lname` fields are lost causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks guys, everything's been helpful.

Answer (score 2):

This will work now

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post" name="frm1" onsubmit="return newPerson()"> <!-- return -->
    First Name: <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"/> <br/>
    Last Name: <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="update"/>
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
var x = 0;
function newPerson(){
    var form = document.frm1; // or : document.forms[0]; for first form
    x++;
    var pname = "p" + x;
    var jj = form.elements["fname"].value;
    var gg = form.elements["lname"].value;
    document.write(x);
    document.write(pname + jj + gg);
    return false; // <-- stops submission
}
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/UARGc/)

Answer (score 1):

Your code had a few issues:

1. Form was getting submitted due to default `submit` action. You have to prevent that from happening by adding `return false;` to your JavaScript function and `return newPerson();` to your form's `onSubmit` attribute.
2. Your `document.write(x)` line was overwriting the page, meaning all the elements that were initially present including `fname` and `lname` are lost and hence could not be accessed. Remove this line.
3. Also instead of `document.write`, have an `outputDiv` and write the output to it. In general doing `document.write` is considered to be bad practice as it re-paints the whole page.

Correcting all the above mentioned issues, your code should look like below to work.

**HTML:**

```
<form name="frm1" onSubmit="return newPerson();">First Name:
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" />
    <br/>Last Name:
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" />
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="update" />
</form>
<div id='outputDiv'></div>
```

**JS:**

```
  x = 0;
  function newPerson() {
      x++;
      console.log(x); //just to see what is the value of x in console. not needed otherwise
      var pname = "p" + x;
      var jj = document.frm1.fname.value;
      var gg = document.frm1.lname.value;
      document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML = pname + jj + gg; //set the computed value to the outputDiv.
      return false;
  }
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FqP8b/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Make following changes to your code. It is working perfectly:

```
<script> 
  var x=0;
  function newPerson(){
    x++;
    document.write(x);
    var pname = "p" + x;
    var jj = document.getElementById('fname').value;
    var gg =document.getElementById('lname').value;
    document.write(pname + jj + gg);
  }
</script>
```

What is the need of `document.write(x);`? You could have easily used `alert(x);`.
One more thing, It is not at all clear what is your purpose behind this code. Please make sure to provide a detailed question in future.

Answer (score 1):

```
TRY THIS to check what's happening:-
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Untitled Document</title> 
<script> 
x=0;
function newPerson(){
x++;
document.write(x);
  // var pname = "p" + x;
  // var jj =document.forms["frm1"]["fname"].value;
  // var gg =document.forms["frm1"]["lname"].value;
  // document.write(pname + jj + gg); 
return false;
}

</script> </head>

<body>

<form name="frm1" onSubmit="return newPerson()">

First Name: <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"/> <br/>
Last Name: <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="update"/>  </form>

</body> </html>

Explanation:- As you submit you form. it calls to your function. document.write executes.
and document.write  will clear document area and will write there value of x.
now when code goes to second line there is no form so there is no value .
```

so this will give javascript error.
    and follow few points:-

```
*onsubmit is used with return , means return true then submit form else not. but in your code form will be submitted in any case.

* As form submit to default action, means self page. page will reload. 
you can check what's happening, by putting breakpoints in firebug, or debug console in any modern browser. and please enable persist log upon navigation.
```

so you will find what happening there.